# Cutting the branch name in __git_ps1 function

Tags: git, mingw-w64, ps1

I have a question related to the `__git_ps1()` function existing in the `mingw64` terminal for `git for windows` application. I would like to have a part of the branch names to be shown.
For example, suppose you work with *Jira* and your branches are created for each story/bug and you name them like `STORY-<STORY_NUMBER>_<some_more_stuff>`. I wanted to cut out the rest after and including the `_` symbol, but have no clue how to do that. I found the function in the `git-prompt.sh` file. I find the function is too long for copying. BTW, it can be found eighter here `/etc/profile.d/git-prompt.sh` or here `/mingw64/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh` relative to the `git` installation folder.

### Edit - Adding the `git-prompt.sh` link

In case you don't have the file, you can find it [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh)

Comment: Can you please post your current `__git_ps1()` function or a link to it

Comment: @danielorn I wanted to, but the function is too long. Let me try to find any on the internet

Comment: @danielorn Please have a look at the edit of the question